# Using download_data() and untar_data() in fastai library

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, deep-learning, fast-ai

I downloaded Fashion MNIST dataset from kaggle using dowload_data() function in fastai library.

`downloaded_data = download_data("https://www.kaggle.com/zalando-research/fashionmnist/download")`

output -

`PosixPath('/root/.fastai/data/download.tgz')`

download_data saves it as .tgz file, now I use untar_data().

`path = untar_data('/root/.fastai/data/download.tgz')`

output -

`PosixPath('/root/.fastai/data/download.tgz')`

Which did not extract .tgz file. How do I use this dataset in fastai library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fastai library, the download_data gives you a `pathlib.PosixPath` file, not the exact file, you need to use another unzipping library to extract the data.

If you just need the MNIST data from fast ai, here's an easier way:

```
from fastai import datasets
import gzip, pickle
MNIST_URL='http://deeplearning.net/data/mnist/mnist.pkl'
path = datasets.download_data(MNIST_URL, ext='.gz')
with gzip.open(path, 'rb') as f:
    ((x_train, y_train), (x_valid, y_valid), _) = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin-1')
```

Comment: isn't `path = untar_data(URLs.MNIST)` easier?